# How do I look over a javascript array without using indexes in YUI?

Tags: javascript, yui

I know that jQuery and prototype have a $.each() function for iterating over each element in an array. Does YUI offer any help with this?

Answer (score 7):

YAHOO.util.Dom has the batch function which has the following signature:

> Any | Array **batch**( el , method , o , override )

Where *el* is a DOM element or an array of DOM elements, *method* is a function that that will be passed each element in the array as its first argument, *o* is an optional second argument, and *override* is a boolean value that determines if the scope should be window (false) or *o* (true)

So you could call it like this:

```
function setDisplay(el, display) {
    el.style.display = display;
}

YAHOO.util.Dom.batch(document.getElementsByTagName('div'), setDisplay, 'none');
```

Perhaps that would serve your needs.

Answer (score 5):

What keeps you from simply *iterating* the array?

```
for(var i=0; i<ary.length; i++)
  // assuming that ary[] contains objects with a DoSometing() method
  ary[i].doSomething();
```

Comment: the poster asked for YUI, didn't he?

Comment: @zladuric: Yes, he did. But it seemed (and still seems) to me that JavaScript frameworks make people forget that there is *actual, simple JavaScript* they could use, and that's what I wanted to point out. Besides, chances are that a for loop outperforms any `array.each(callback)` implementation.

Comment: ok. I didn't want to get into it, I just thought that these kinds of answers (which effectively don't answer the question, but rather point to something else) would go to comments to question, not answers. I may be stupid, though.

Answer (score 2):

In YUI3:

```
Y.Array.each(myArray, function(element) {
    Y.log(element);
});
```

or even:

```
Y.Array.each(myArray, function(element, index, array) {
    ...
});
```